# Is MSMQ thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, msmq

I have multiple processes monitoring an MSMQ queue. I want to do multi-step operations like first peek the message and then based on some criteria receive the message. A single message may pass the receiving criteria of multiple processes so that more than one process may try to receive the same message. Will these operations be thread safe? If not what should I do to prevent one process from failing to receive the message that other process has already received?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operations themselves are thread safe. However, if you perform a multi-step operation you may find that the results are not consistent (for example, peeking to see if data is in the queue, then calling to receive the data, only to discover it's not there any longer).

Comment: Please note: from .NET Framework 4 onward, according to MSDN, `Only the GetAllMessages method is thread safe`. I suggest updating the answer to reflect this, so that the readers won't be confused.

Answer (score 14):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx):

> Only the following methods are thread safe: BeginPeek, BeginReceive, EndPeek(IAsyncResult), EndReceive(IAsyncResult), GetAllMessages, Peek, and Receive.

Comment: Please note that the .Net 4 version of the documentation for MessageQueue states that only GetAllMessages() is thread safe. I'll assume this is an actual change since erroneous documentation would presumably have been updated in-line with the .Net 4 docs.

Comment: Notably the Send() method was found to be not thread safe in my unit test, locking on the MessageQueue object solved various nullreference etc exceptions that were being thrown in my parallel loop.

Comment: @Kaido: Did the unlocked `MessageQueue.Send()` result in errors? Or what was the behavior you experienced?

Comment: Yes, exceptions were thrown in the msft platform code when I called MessageQueue.Send() on one instance from multiple threads simultaneously. Solved with lock(myLockObj){MessageQueue.Send();}

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested in a [blog entry](http://msmq.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!393534E869CE55B7!293.entry) I wrote on this subject.

In short, MSMQ C++ API is thread safe, but not all System.Messaging methods are thread safe. In the blog entry I discuss how to call MessageQueue.Send in a thread-safe way.